# Watch OS: Swift KVO for BatteryState is not working

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, watchos-4

I want to monitor watch battery state so i have added KVO for battery state like this

```
private func setupNotification() {

    WKInterfaceDevice.current().addObserver(self,
                                            forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKInterfaceDevice.batteryState),
                                            options: [.new],
                                            context: nil)
}

override public func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                                  of object: Any?,
                                  change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?,
                                  context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == #keyPath(WKInterfaceDevice.batteryState) {
        switch WKInterfaceDevice.current().batteryState {
        case .charging:
            self.stopMonitoring()
        case .unplugged:
            if BatteryManager.batteryLevel > Constant.Battery.criticalValue {
                self.startMonitoring()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Also I have added before

```
func enableBatteryMonitoring() {
    WKInterfaceDevice.current().isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
}
```

But it's not getting called, when in/out plug charger.
Any permission or else what i'm missing?

Comment: Is your watch app running in the foreground when the battery state changes? If not, that could cause problems, because watch apps have very limited means of running in the background.

Comment: @MikeMertsock: Yes the app is in foreground

Answer (score 2):

As far as I saw from the documentation is not stated clearly that this property is KVO compliant.
In the WatchKit documentation they say:

> If battery monitoring is enabled, this property is set to a value
>   between 0.0 (0% charge) and 1.0 (100% charge). When the batteryState
>   property is set to WKInterfaceDeviceBatteryState.unknown (for example,
>   when battery monitoring is disabled), the value is -1.0.

So it seems that `isBatteryMonitoringEnabled` it just enable you to read the battery by asking its value (by polling) instead of observing it.

Comment: By adding an observer you are implying that is KVO compliant and probably it is not. For instance also `UIDevice` exposes the same property but documentation says that you can register using `NotificationCenter` to specific notifications, on WatchKit side there is no such statement.

Comment: They are 2 separated protocols, for instance in most of UIKit classes KVC is present while KVO no, or probably overridden

Comment: I try to add `.initial` in options array then it calls once when app runs only.